# Convolution of a particular function

Tags: integration, convolution

> I want to show that
> $$
> e^{\alpha t} ∗ e^{\beta t} = \frac{e^{\alpha t} − e^{\beta t}}{\alpha − \beta},
> \quad \forall \alpha \ne \beta
> $$

I just know that : $(f ∗ g)(t) = \int_0^t f(t − s) g(s) ds$

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: $$e^{\alpha t}*e^{\beta t}=\int_0^te^{\alpha(t-s)}e^{\beta s}ds=e^{\alpha t}\int_0^te^{(\beta-\alpha)s}ds=e^{\alpha t}\frac{e^{(\beta -\alpha)t}-1}{\beta-\alpha}$$

Answer (score 0):

So when you plug into your definition, you let $f(t) = e^{\alpha t}$ and $g(t) = e^{\beta t}$, and you get
$$
(f*g)(t)
 = \int_0^t e^{\alpha(t-s)}e^{\beta s}ds
 = e^{\alpha t} \int_0^t e^{s(\beta - \alpha)}ds
$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes of course it was obvious, we obtain : $e^{αt}\frac{e^{(β−α)t}−1}{β−α} = \frac{e^{βt}−e^{αt}}{β−α} $ and if we multiply by $\frac{-1}{-1}$ we are done